# Fill contacts from Inbox

Tags: microsoft-outlook, user-interface, address-book

Sometimes it is annoying when Outlook can't find recipient and autocomplete with address.
Is it possible somehow to ask Outlook to fill up my contacts from send and received folders?

Answer (score -1):

If your aim is to have those recipients show up as an autocomplete suggestion, then populating the Outlook contacts list won't actually help you here. Outlook's autocomplete functionality doesn't use the Outlook contacts, it gets automatically generated when you send emails out to populate it's hidden cache.

For some more info see https://www.msoutlook.info/question/filling-the-autocomplete-list-with-contact-addresses

Where you have existing contacts entries that you want to show up in the autocomplete list, the suggested fix is to :

1. Set Outlook to "Work Offline"
2. Create a new email message
3. Add all the required email addresses to the message and (*making sure you're in offline mode!*) send the message.
4. Delete the email from the Outbox
5. Put Outlook back into Online mode.

You could potentially do similar with emails you've received, though it would be more time consuming, for instance reply to each of the emails you've received (while Outlook's in offline mode) to get Outlook to add those addresses to the cache, then remove them from the Outbox.

Comment: -1 because autocomplete will use both the autocomplete list AND contacts.

Comment: @LPChip And you base that assertion on what? Unless it's a recent change in the latest version of Outlook, it has never used the Contacts for autocompletion, and the fact that https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/troubleshoot/contacts/information-about-the-outlook-autocomplete-list indicates the same behaviour exists in the latest versions as it did in 2010 and beyond I'd suggests that hasn't changed.

Comment: I base that on the fact that I tested it in my local outlook and it works there. I type the name of the contact, then press the button Check Names, and it auto matches with the local contact, or optionally press To: and select it from my contacts there.

Comment: So when you manually click Check Names, Outlook goes and checks the Contacts. That's not Autocomplete. If Autocomplete did check contacts as you suggested you wouldn't need to do that as it'd display it automatically as you typed. That said it does look like Autocomplete also populates its list when you create a new contact, but I only see autocomplete results for contacts I've just created, not for any address that's been in my Contacts for a long time (likely predating my current Outlook profile).

Comment: OP never asked to get the contacts in the autocomplete. They just tell us that they are not in auto complete, so OP is looking for an alternate way to get to these email addresses

Comment: I'm afraid it is not possible, since Outlook builds the Auto-Complete List by saving the names and addresses you've previously used when sending messages. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/manage-suggested-recipients-in-the-to-cc-and-bcc-boxes-with-auto-complete-dbe46e31-c098-4881-8cf7-66b037bce23e